# How to make my HTML image button go to url

Tags: html, wordpress

I made a couple of buttons to download an app from the playstore and appstore. I put them on my theme and I am having an issue getting them to work like buttons. Although the href attribute is set, it does not actually work as a button. When hovering it, the cursor does not change, and when clicking it, it doesn't go to the URL specified. Can anyone give me a hand. I have confirmed the php setting you see below for the URL does hold a value. It is for the wordpress theme customizer incase you are wondering.

```
<a class="storebtns" href="<?php echo mytheme_theme_mod( 'hero_appstore_button_url' ); ?>">
  <img src="http://sandbox.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/appstore.png" width="170"/>
</a>
```

Here is the rendered HTML. This is why it is so confusing. It is showing a URL.

```
<a class="storebtns" href="test.com">
                <img src="http://sandbox.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/appstore.png" width="170" style="margin-right: 15px">
                </a>
```

Comment: using developer tools, can you confirm that the PHP is actually echoing that url properly and that the url is what you think it is?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: The rendered HTML is showing the link as it should. I will post the rendered HTML to the question.

Comment: When doing an absolute url like `test.com`, you need to have the protocol, like this: `http://test.com/`, otherwise it will try to interpret it like a relative url and try to go to `http://yoursitesurl.com/thepage.php/test.com`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3KyGQ/ something else is wrong in your code. Can you show us the CSS and Javascript that might be affecting this?

Comment: Thanks for that. I did realize that after. I totally forgot about that. My issue was actually the Z-index of the button. It is in an area with alot of elements in the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually nothing to do with the HTML at all. It was the Z-index of the button. It is in an area on my theme that has alot of different elements grouped together. So the Z-index was putting the button behind the others so even though you could see the button, you couldn't click it or see a different cursor.